# How to generate exceptions when trying to matching input from list

Tags: java, exception

Slightly odd question but I'm practicing exception handling with try catch blocks at the minute and I'm trying to generate an exception caused by a user entering values that are not on a predefined list. I am unsure of how to generate the errors needed to work on the exception handling. The simplest possible example to generate the error is fine, I'm just using months of the year. I have tried adding them to an arraylist and running a months.contains() line but it's not giving me any errors if I enter something that's not there.

I'm normally fantastic at generating exceptions, but somethings changed

Comment: You probably want to do something like `if(!list.contains(element)) { throw new NoSuchElementException("Element " + element + " not found"); }`.

Comment: Ah, sorry @Thomas , forgot a part of what we're trying to do. They want us to focus on try catch blocks at the moment, so I can't if into the exception. Apparently too many of my predecessors have done that and they've pre-emptively asked us to practice the try catch blocks

Comment: Well, you could surround that with a try-catch block to catch the exception and handle it. If you're not allowed to actually throw an exception yourself try to use list methods that throw exceptions (see their JavaDocs) or try to extract the element (so you get `null`) and then call a method on it to provoke a NullPointerException.

Comment: Can you not just do `throw new RuntimeException("bad thing happened");` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an enum for this.

Declare this outside you method.

```
enum MONTHES {
   JAN, FEB, MAR;
};
```

Inside your method do this.

```
MONTHES.valueOf("FOO");
```

This will throw an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: OOh, thank you. Would never have thought of this but it's exactly what I was looking for and actually serving as a nice intro to Enums